# How can i code for edit a character in a txt file with python

Tags: python, edit

it keep stop run after asking the old code and also clear my roti canai file. So what can I do for it.(even is changing all the code)

```
def modify_roti_canai():
    print("\n*-- Modify Roti Canai Menu --*\n")
    file = open("roticanai", "r+")
    print(file.read())
    old_code = input("Enter a Item Code for Modifying (e.g. RC01): ")
    if len(old_code) == 4:
        new_code = input("New Food Item Code: ")
        new_name = input("New Food Item Name: ")
        new_price = input("New Food Item Price: ")
        file.write(new_code + "," + new_name + "," + new_price + "\n")
    else:
        print("Item Code Not Existed, Please try again!")
    file.close()
```

*inside my roticanai file is exist few of record:

```
RC01,ROTI CANAI KOSONG,1.60
RC02,ROTI CANAI SUSU,3.90
RC03,ROTI CANAI CHEESE,4.50
RC04,ROTI CANAI PLANTA,3.90
RC05,ROTI CANAI TISSUE,4.50
```

Comment: `os.remove("roticanai")` - I guess that deletes the file.  What makes you wonder that its content is gone? And if you look for `file_w.write`, it doesn't write much either.

Comment: replace `if len(s) == 4:` with `if len(old_code) == 4:`

Comment: oh, thank a lot, the code is much better but how I make it replace my specific code, like the old code I type RC01 and I want it be RC14, how I can coordinate its location?

Comment: how can i defined the first column in the txt file ya? mean the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s is an empty string. If you are comparing the length(i.e 0) with 4, then if statement evaluates to False. It doesn't add data to "temp.txt" file. It will an empty file renamed as "roticanai".

Comment: thankss ! it is much better to understand with it, and how could I specifically modify the item code ya?

Comment: You just want to modify the item code alone or to change the entire line of data?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the filenames as required
**Use the same filename, no need of temp file

```
def modify_roti_canai():
    print("\n*-- Modify Roti Canai Menu --*\n")

    with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
        #Gets each line of the file as list item
        data = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]
        print(data)

    #separates codes from data
    codes= [x.split(',')[0] for x in data]
    print(codes)

    old_code = input("Enter a Item Code for Modifying (e.g. RC01): ")

    if len(old_code) == 4:
        #removes the old code line from data using the index of entered code
        data.pop(codes.index(old_code))
        new_code = input("New Food Item Code: ")
        new_name = input("New Food Item Name: ")
        new_price = input("New Food Item Price: ")
        new_data = f"{new_code},{new_name},{new_price}"
        #appends new data to the data list
        data.append(new_data)
        #Writes the data list to file
        with open('test.txt','w') as file:
            for e in data:
                file.write(e + '\n')
            print(file.read())
    else:
        print("Item Code Not Existed, Please try again!")
```